# PHP mail form to display checkbox results

Tags: php, forms, email, checkbox

I'm working with a PHP mail form and so far all is working well. It is returning everything from the form except the checkbox results. For them, it just says 'array'. I've searched high and low for a fix but I can't seem to get it working using the solutions I have found online. Part of the issue is that I'm not 100% sure 'where' in the mail form to put the code. My PHP mail form is as follows:

```
<?php

// OPTIONS - PLEASE CONFIGURE THESE BEFORE USE!
$yourEmail = "myemailhere@myemail.com"; // the email address you wish to receive these mails through
$yourWebsite = "My Website name"; // the name of your website
$thanksPage = 'thanks.php'; // URL to 'thanks for sending mail' page; leave empty to keep message on the same page
$maxPoints = 4; // max points a person can hit before it refuses to submit - recommend 4

// --- DO NOT EDIT BELOW HERE -----------------------
$error_msg = null;
$result = null;

function isBot()
{
    $bots = array("Indy", "Blaiz", "Java", "libwww-perl", "Python", "OutfoxBot", "User-Agent", "PycURL", "AlphaServer", "T8Abot", "Syntryx", "WinHttp", "WebBandit", "nicebot");
    $isBot = false;

    foreach ($bots as $bot) {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $bot) !== false) $isBot = true;
    }

    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == " ") $isBot = true;
    exit("Bots not allowed.</p>");
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    function clean($data)
    {
        $data = trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($data)));
        return $data;
    }

    $points = (int)0;
    $badwords = array("adult", "beastial", "bestial", "blowjob", "clit", "cum", "cunilingus", "cunillingus", "cunnilingus", "####", "ejaculate", "fag", "felatio", "fellatio", "####", "fuk", "fuks", "gangbang", "gangbanged", "gangbangs", "hotsex", "hardcode", "jism", "jiz", "orgasim", "orgasims", "orgasm", "orgasms", "phonesex", "phuk", "phuq", "porn", "pussies", "pussy", "spunk", "xxx", "viagra", "phentermine", "tramadol", "adipex", "advai", "alprazolam", "ambien", "ambian", "amoxicillin", "antivert", "blackjack", "backgammon", "texas", "holdem", "poker", "carisoprodol", "ciara", "ciprofloxacin", "debt", "dating", "porn", "link=", "voyeur");
    $exploits = array("content-type", "bcc:", "cc:", "document.cookie", "onclick", "onload", "javascript");

    foreach ($badwords as $word) {
        if (strpos($_POST['message'], $word) !== false) $points += 2;
    }

    foreach ($exploits as $exploit) {
        if (strpos($_POST['message'], $exploit) !== false) $points += 2;
    }

    if (strpos($_POST['message'], "http://") !== false || strpos($_POST['message'], "www.") !== false) $points += 2;
    if (isset($_POST['nojs'])) $points += 1;
    if (preg_match("/(<.*>)/i", $_POST['message'])) $points += 2;
    if (strlen($_POST['name']) < 3) $points += 1;
    if (strlen($_POST['message']) < 15 || strlen($_POST['message'] > 1500)) $points += 2;

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $_POST[$key] = trim($value);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $error_msg .= "Name, e-mail and comments are required fields. \n";
    } elseif (strlen($_POST['name']) > 15) {
        $error_msg .= "The name field is limited at 15 characters. Your first name or nickname will do! \n";
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-'\s]*$/", stripslashes($_POST['name']))) {
        $error_msg .= "The name field must not contain special characters. \n";
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i', strtolower($_POST['email']))) {
        $error_msg .= "That is not a valid e-mail address. \n";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['url']) && !preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(:(\d+))?\/?/i', $_POST['url'])) {
        $error_msg .= "Invalid website url.";
    }

    if ($error_msg == NULL && $points <= $maxPoints) {
        $subject = "Desktop Support Form Email";
        $message = "You received this e-mail message through your website: \n\n";

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
            $message .= ucwords($key) . ": " . clean($val) . "\r\n";
        }

        $message .= 'IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\r\n";

        if (strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], "Win")) {
            $headers = "From: $yourEmail \r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}";
        } else {
            $headers = "From: $yourWebsite <$yourEmail> \r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}";
        }

        if (mail($yourEmail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            if (!empty($thanksPage)) {
                header("Location: $thanksPage");
                exit;
            } else {
                $result = 'Your mail was successfully sent.';
            }
        } else {
            $error_msg = 'Your mail could not be sent this time.';
        }
    } else {
        if (empty($error_msg)) {
            $error_msg = 'Your mail looks too much like spam, and could not be sent this time. [' . $points . ']';
        }
    }
}

function get_data($var)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$var])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[$var]);
}
```

My HTML is stndard form fare. I have assigned 'name="feedback[]"' to the checkboxes as I had found that naming them the same and using the square brackets facilitates the passing of the checkbox information. I just dont know how to enter it into my mail form above. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Which `$_POST` variable(s) is/are assigned by the checkboxes?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML, any JS/jQuery if you use that to send your form, and then show us a print_r($_POST) in your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Since your checkboxes are posted in an array `'name="feedback[]"'`, you need to check if the value is an array - `is_array($val)` before adding the value to your message. Here is a simple example -

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)){
        foreach ($val as $k=>$v) {
                $message .= ucwords($key) . "[" . $k . "]: " . clean($v) . "\r\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        $message .= ucwords($key) . ": " . clean($val) . "\r\n";
    }
}
```

This would then set your checkbox values as -

```
$message .= "FEEDBACK[0]: ....";
$message .= "FEEDBACK[1]: ....";
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help!  I'm very new to all this so not 100% sure about what to do. Are you saying that I should replace the existing  "foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {" block of code in my file with the example you posted above? sorry to be a pain! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you would want to change your `foreach ($_POST as $key => $val){
$message .= ucwords($key) . ": " . clean($val) . "\r\n";}` to the code I posted. The second portion is the same as your original code, where the first checks to see if the post is an array, and then loops through the array and then appends it in the same way as your code.